# How to "SUMIF" in multyple Condition. (Google spredsheet)

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use SUMIF in multyple condition.
I have a two sheets.

sheet1
Row have SKU (UNIQ) , total_quantity

Sheet2
Row have flag , SKU(related with sheet1) , quantity

if sheet2 flag is true I want to add quantity in total_quantity with same SKU.

Comment: I assume total_quantity is the column you need the formula for.

Answer (score 0):

DSUM - there are a few database style formulas, looks like DSUM is what you want https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1368827

Comment: DSUM is a little slow, hope you don't need lots of them

Answer (score 0):

If the first total_quantity cell is Sheet1!B2, then in that cell:

`=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet2!C$2:C;Sheet2!B$2:B=A2;Sheet2!A$2:A)))`

which you can manually fill down; alternatively, this may be converted to an array formula that will automatically populate down the column:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A);MMULT(A2:A=TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!B2:B);Sheet2!A2:A*Sheet2!C2:C);IFERROR(1/0)))`